# How to identify blanks in the last column using awk?

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this. The  first line is the header.

```
"variant_id" "hg38_chr" "hg38_pos" "ref_allele" "alt_allele" "hg19_chr" "hg19_pos"
"chr10_100000235_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100000235" "C" "T" "chr10" 101759992
"chr10_100002628_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100002628" "A" "C" "chr10" 
"chr10_100004827_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100004827" "A" "C" "chr10" 101764584
"chr10_100005358_G_C_b38" "chr10" "100005358" "G" "C" "chr10" 101765115
"chr10_100005711_G_A_b38" "chr10" "100005711" "G" "A" "chr10" 101765468
"chr10_100006780_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100006780" "C" "T" "chr10" 101766537
"chr10_100007241_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100007241" "C" "T" "chr10" 101766998
"chr10_100008640_A_G_b38" "chr10" "100008640" "A" "G" "chr10" 
"chr10_100009013_G_A_b38" "chr10" "100009013" "G" "A" "chr10" 101768770
```

How do I identify the empty fields in the last column?
I tried the command below:

```
awk '$7==" "' file.txt > blanks.txt
awk '{if($7==" ") print}' file.txt > blanks.txt
```

Both gave empty files.

The result of  blanks.txt should be

```
"chr10_100002628_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100002628" "A" "C" "chr10" 
"chr10_100008640_A_G_b38" "chr10" "100008640" "A" "G" "chr10"
```

Comment: By default, `awk` removes starting/ending blanks and one or more blanks are used as field separators. So, you cannot have a field with just blank characters. You can check if it is empty. Also, please change your sample with some empty fields.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. However again - are the fields tab- or space-separated. And another question: Your field values are all in double-quotes. Does that mean you can have fields where the field value itself contains a space (considered protected by the qouting)?

Comment: Can any other field also be blank/missing?

Comment: Normally fields are quoted when they can contain a newline or the field separator (which appears to be a blank for your data). Can your quoted fields contain any white space? Can they contain double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last alternative on this answer is more strict on what will be accepted, and is  independent of fields being delimited by tabs and/or spaces.

But, to start:

If the last field is empty, there will be only 6 fields (if delimited on spaces or tabs). If you want those lines printed, this will do:

```
$ awk ' NF<7 {print}' infile

"chr10_100002628_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100002628" "A" "C" "chr10" 
"chr10_100008640_A_G_b38" "chr10" "100008640" "A" "G" "chr10"
```

The `{print}` command is not actually required, as awk does print by default on expressions that are true, removed on next solutions (thanks [FelixJN](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/123460/felixjn)).

If you also need the headers, then add:

```
$ awk '(NF<7) || (NR==1)' infile

"variant_id" "hg38_chr" "hg38_pos" "ref_allele" "alt_allele" "hg19_chr" "hg19_pos"
"chr10_100002628_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100002628" "A" "C" "chr10" 
"chr10_100008640_A_G_b38" "chr10" "100008640" "A" "G" "chr10"
```

And, if you want to keep the lines that have enough fields, do:

```
$ awk '(NF>=7) || (NR==1)' infile

"variant_id" "hg38_chr" "hg38_pos" "ref_allele" "alt_allele" "hg19_chr" "hg19_pos"
"chr10_100000235_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100000235" "C" "T" "chr10" 101759992
"chr10_100004827_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100004827" "A" "C" "chr10" 101764584
"chr10_100005358_G_C_b38" "chr10" "100005358" "G" "C" "chr10" 101765115
"chr10_100005711_G_A_b38" "chr10" "100005711" "G" "A" "chr10" 101765468
"chr10_100006780_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100006780" "C" "T" "chr10" 101766537
"chr10_100007241_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100007241" "C" "T" "chr10" 101766998
"chr10_100009013_G_A_b38" "chr10" "100009013" "G" "A" "chr10" 101768770
```

If you require a solution that doesn't depend on the fact that there is a missing last file but, instead, ensure that there is a trailing number at the end of the line, use:

```
$ awk '/[0-9]+[ \t]*$/ || (NR==1)' infile

"variant_id" "hg38_chr" "hg38_pos" "ref_allele" "alt_allele" "hg19_chr" "hg19_pos"
"chr10_100000235_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100000235" "C" "T" "chr10" 101759992
"chr10_100004827_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100004827" "A" "C" "chr10" 101764584
"chr10_100005358_G_C_b38" "chr10" "100005358" "G" "C" "chr10" 101765115
"chr10_100005711_G_A_b38" "chr10" "100005711" "G" "A" "chr10" 101765468
"chr10_100006780_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100006780" "C" "T" "chr10" 101766537
"chr10_100007241_C_T_b38" "chr10" "100007241" "C" "T" "chr10" 101766998
"chr10 100009013_G_A_b38" "chr10" "100009013" "G" "A" "chr10" 101768770
"chr10 100009013 G_A_b38" "chr10" "100009013" "G" "A" "chr10" 101768770
"chr10_100009013_G_A_b38" "chr10" "100009013" "G" "A" "chr10" 101768770
```

That will not be affected by any other field missing, and will be independent of which field delimiter is used (space and/or tab).

That is assuming the last field is a number **not** enclosed in double quotes, but that is easy to change, if needed.

And, to strictly conform to the output requested on your question:

```
$ awk '!/[0-9]+[ \t]*$/ && NR>1' infile
"chr10_100002628_A_C_b38" "chr10" "100002628" "A" "C" "chr10" 
"chr10_100008640_A_G_b38" "chr10" "100008640" "A" "G" "chr10"
```